# PDE - how to transform this pde to an easier one using change of varriable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this PDE its actually an ADE and I can put it in one of these forms.

[image: Advection Diffusion Equation]

All characters in all four equations are constants with exception of x, y, t and C.

I have listed the equations in order of preference.

I need a change of variable that can transform any one of the equations into a PDE having constant coefficients.

Any other method or approach, material or link that can help in solving any one of these four equations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the homogeneous equations, 3 and 4, convert any one of them to laplace space, or simply write 3 or 4 in laplace space.

then use separation of variable, to obtain two separate equations in x and y.

multiply the new equations by x and y respectively to put them in a form solvable using the confluent hypergeometric function (Kummer function of the first kind or Whittaker function).

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Other_equations

Afterwards, any stable inversion algorithm can be used to convert the final answer into real time space.